# Multibar chart(nvd3) x axis label in not centered

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Using nvd3 multibar chart. When having minimum bars x axis label does not display in center like y axis.

Sample code to generate x axis label.

```
chart = nv.models.multiBarChart().margin({
            top: 30,
            right: 28,
            bottom: 50,
            left: 60
        })
        .x(function(d) {
            return d.x
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return d.y
        })
        .color(d3.scale.myColors().range());

chart.xAxis
        .showMaxMin(true)
        .axisLabel(xAxisLabel)
        .tickFormat(xAxisTickFormat)
        .tickValues(xaxisValues);
```

[image]

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you put your code in a fiddle, so someone can have a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound strange but try swapping the order of `axisLabel` and `showMaxMin` like the following :

```
chart.xAxis
   .axisLabel(xAxisLabel) // axisLabel first
   .showMaxMin(true)
   .tickFormat(xAxisTickFormat)
   .tickValues(xaxisValues);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your solution did not help.

Comment: @OnkarJanwa can you put your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so someone can have a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the next workaround. Hope it helps:

```
var transitions = 0;
d3.select(this.tag + ' svg').transition().each( "start", function() {
                    transitions++;
                }).each( "end", function() {
                    if( --transitions === 0 ) {
                        alignaxisCallback();
                    }
                });



 function alignaxisCallback(){          
       var axisWidth = d3.select('.nv-x').node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
       d3.select('.nv-x').select('.nv-axislabel').attr('x', axisWidth / 2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
chart.xAxis.axisLabelDistance(LABEL_OFFSET);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by updating nvd3 to version 1.8.4 or higher.